# Temporary bathroom flooring before full remodel

Tags: bathroom, flooring, subfloor

We have mold underneath the old linoleum flooring in one of our bathrooms around the toilet. The linoleum is original to the house (37 years old). At some point in the next couple of years, we'll be remodeling the bathroom with a new tub.

I want to remove the linoleum and replace/repair any subfloor that is moldy or needs to be repaired sooner rather than later, but it doesn't make sense to tile over it if we're going to replace the tub within a couple of years. What are some ideas for the best solution for "temporary" flooring that isn't too expensive and is easy to install and remove, while also being appropriate for the conditions in a bathroom?

Comment: Maybe borrow some money and do the renovation now.

Answer (score 1):

Vinyl sheet flooring (which may be called lineoleum, but isn't) would be a good temporary fix if you've cured the leakage or condensation leading to your original mold issue. A properly cut piece will fill the space with no seams (unless it's a huge space) and can be simply laid in or attached with double stick tape at the edges.

Peel and stick tiles are less daunting (no need to cut the whole sheet just so before installing - but that's a simple matter of making a good paper pattern first) but have lots of seams and won't do well in spills if they are not cleaned up more or less instantly.